# XPath to separately select each of two values in a table cell?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<td _ngcontent-wp class="align-middle">
 "4.79728"
  <small _ngcontent-wp class="neo_red_dark"> -0.08% </small>
</td>
```

My XPath as follows:

```
(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3])[1]
```

It works, but it gets two values together (`4.79728 -0.08%`). How can I get them separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value before the space and after the space using:

[`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-substring-before) and [`substring-after()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-substring-after)

or change your XPath to target the `text()` descendants of the `td` instead of the `td` itself (which is producing the calculated text value).

In order to select `"4.79728"`:

```
(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3])[1]/text()
```

In order to select `-0.08%`:

```
(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3])[1]/small/text()
```

Comment: thanks. But I couldn't manage it.  My code as follows: 

Fiyat = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@class="table"]//tbody/tr/td[3])[1]')
print (Fiyat.text)

Comment: Thanks. 
Managed to get the 2nd part:

Fiyat_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/small)[1]')
print (Fiyat_2.text)

how can I can't get the 1st part alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate with XPath questions which XPath version you are using.

If it's version 1.0, remember that the set of data types you can return is very limited: a single string, number, or boolean, or a node-set. And some APIs only allow you to return a node-set.

Your current query is returning a node-set containing one node, namely a `td` element, whose string value contains the concatenation of all the text within. You could return a node-set containing all the text nodes individually by appending `//text()` to the query. But of course, it won't always be the case that the two numbers are in separate text nodes.

Comment: thanks. But I couldn't manage it.  My code as follows: 

Fiyat = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@class="table"]//tbody/tr/td[3])[1]')
print (Fiyat.text)

Comment: Thanks. 
Managed to get the 2nd part:

Fiyat_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/small)[1]')
print (Fiyat_2.text)

how can I can't get the 1st part alone.

Comment: Why have you ignored my suggestion to use `//text()`?

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your patience. I'm a newbe.
Your suggestion works when I try it with Chrome Developers Tool. But when I tried to execute it in jupyter notebook it gives the following error: 
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/text())[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  My code in Jupyter: 
Fiyat = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/text())[1]')
print (Fiyat.text)

Comment: I don't know Jupyter, but it sounds reasonable that a method called `find_element_by_xpath` would expect the XPath to select element nodes. Does Jupyter have a different method that can be used to select text nodes? If not, then you're stuck.